# Does packetbeat support interception

Tags: elasticsearch, packet-sniffers, packetbeat

Assume that I have to monitoring MySQL and I need to interception some specific queries by specific users on specific tables  .(I known that I can configure from MySQL but just for example to describe my question)

Example : 
Query issue :

```
SELECT * FROM Salary WHERE user = 'CEO'
```

Does packetbeat support someway interception those illegal queries or packets when sniffing ?

Answer (score 0):

Packetbeat will only detect those queries (like any other query) and ship them to Elasticsearch, but Packetbeat does not provide a way to prevent those queries from running, it's not its job.

However, using Kibana you can then analyze who did what on which tables and take actions (after the fact).